# Titanium Studio - Putting my detailed data into a table

Tags: json, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

I have a data table and on eventlistener click, the row becomes a detailed window with the data of the row selected. I have the data as labels, but I want to display some of the data as a table with row titles (particularly my vars, mon, tues, weds, thurs, fri, sat, sund). I attempted to create a table within the eventlistener, but it did not appear. how would I approach this? Below is my code:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var data = [];

var barList = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    height: 366,
    width: 320,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
win.add(barList);
barList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Ti.API.info('data: ' + JSON.stringify(e.rowData.data));
    var detail = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        data: e.rowData.data, // use rowData
        title: e.rowData.data.name, // now you can access name as well as address
    });

    var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: JSON.stringify(e.rowData.data.address),
        top: 10
    });
    detail.add(lbl); // just so you can see it here as well

     var mon = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.mon_special,
        top: 30
    });
    detail.add(mon); 

    var tues = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.tues_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(tues); 

    var weds = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.weds_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(weds); 

    var thurs = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.thurs_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(thurs); 

    var fri = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.fri_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(fri); 

    var sat = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.sat_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(sat); 

    var sund = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: e.rowData.data.sun_special,
        top: 50
    });
    detail.add(sund); 


    detail.open({
        modal: true
    });
});

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function () {
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.info(json.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className: 'bar-row',
            data: json[i].bar, // pass everything because you also use name later on
            hasChild: true,
            filter: json[i].bar.name
        });
        var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text: json[i].bar.name,
            font: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            left: 70,
            top: 5,
            height: 20,
            width: 210
        });
        row.add(titleLabel);
        var addressLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text: json[i].bar.address,
            font: {
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            },
            left: 70,
            top: 25,
            height: 40,
            width: 200
        });
        row.add(addressLabel);
        var iconImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            text: json[i].bar.logo_file_name,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            left: 10,
            top: 10
        });
        row.add(iconImage);
        data.push(row);
    }
    barList.setData(data);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/bars.json');
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

as your new to Titanium it think it is difficult to put data

we can approch this type of method in following ways

1) store the data you called i mean your bar dat

```
 var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
 var data = [];

 var json=''


 var barList = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
   height: 366,
   width: 320,
   top: 0,
   left: 0
   });
  win.add(barList);


var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function () {
json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
Ti.API.info(json.length);
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        className: 'bar-row',
        data: json[i].bar, // pass everything because you also use name later on
        hasChild: true,
        filter: json[i].bar.name
    });
    var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: json[i].bar.name,
        font: {
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        left: 70,
        top: 5,
        height: 20,
        width: 210
    });
    row.add(titleLabel);
    var addressLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: json[i].bar.address,
        font: {
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: 'normal'
        },
        left: 70,
        top: 25,
        height: 40,
        width: 200
    });
    row.add(addressLabel);
    var iconImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        text: json[i].bar.logo_file_name,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        left: 10,
        top: 10
    });
    row.add(iconImage);
    data.push(row);
}
barList.setData(data);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://site.com/bars.json');
xhr.send();


barList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

   var newwindow =require('tabledetails')
   var wind= new newwindow(json[e.index])  /// here we are sending particular bar data
   wind.open({modal:true})
 })
```

2) show the details using the data

-----> tabledetails.js

```
 function details(data){

 var details =Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor="#fff"})
 var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: JSON.stringify(data.address),
    top: 10
});
detail.add(lbl); // just so you can see it here as well

 var mon = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: data.mon_special,
    top: 30
});
detail.add(mon); 

var tues = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: data.tues_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(tues); 

var weds = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: data.weds_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(weds); 

var thurs = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: e.rowData.data.thurs_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(thurs); 

var fri = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: data.fri_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(fri); 

var sat = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: e.rowData.data.sat_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(sat); 

var sund = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: data.sun_special,
    top: 50
});
detail.add(sund); 


 return details;
}
 module.exports=detials
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are a lot of inconsistencies in your code and errors.

Comment: where do you felt inconsistent

Comment: You have e.rowData.dat.thurs_special, but then data.weds_special. You have details.add and detail.add and when I make the corrections I get the new window without any data